# Queryset ".dates(...)" returns a non distinct DateTimeQueryset of datetime objects

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

For a `QuerySet` of blog entries, I want to create a `DateQuerySet` of the months in which those posts were made. The query is:

```
dates = Entry.published.all().dates('pub_date', 'month')
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates)

> "month" returns a list of all distinct year/month values for the field.

If I have 4 entries with dates :

- (2012, Feb, 3rd)
- (2012, Feb, 2nd)
- (2012, Jan, 24th)
- (2011, Dec, 28th)

I expect to get 3 datetime objects returned; one for `Dec`, `Jan`, `Feb`, instead I get 4 returned, one for each of the original dates

Is this expected behaviour? I've tried adding `distinct()` to the query, but it still returns every date.

---

**UPDATE**

A simple way to fix this is make a `Set` from the `DateQuerySet`:

```
dates = Entry.published.all().dates('pub_date', 'month')
return set(dates)
```

This removes the duplicates `datetime` objects but I still don't understand why this is happening (or if I am misunderstanding how dates() works)

Comment: I am curious, what does dates = Entry.published.dates('pub_date', 'month') return?

Comment: It returns a `DateQuerySet` which is basically a list of `datetime` objects. It returns one for every entry in the original queryset, regardless of whether or not the occur in the same month of not

Comment: does it also return duplicate dates as does the version with the all() call?

Comment: are you using the default Manager?

Comment: No, but the `published` manager inherits from the defaults and simply filters out Entries from the future

Comment: to debug I would first try it with the default manager and then with a custom one and see if they are different.

Answer (score 1):

Your symptoms sound exactly like a `GROUP BY` query with ordering.

You can `print query.query` to see if there's ordering being applied to a field that would be added to the `SELECT`, thus making all of those distinct as well.

```
Entry.published.dates('pub_date', 'month').order_by()
```

Comment: Oops, forgot about this question - my hack fixed it. I'll check this out shortly

Answer (score 0):

`datetimes()` instead of `dates()`, is a good idea in datetime-type objects situation.

My Environment:

- win10 + python3.6.8
- django2.2.12

FYI:

- datetimes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes
- dates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#dates